# How to join with many conditions on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on writing a query that is able to check multiple rows of the same user. If the combination of the same user's records doesn't provides the required information I need, (remember it is combination of all records a user has, not a single one), the user is considered passed.

For example: There are two tables.

One is "user" which keep user's personal information:

```
id client_id first_name last_name date_of_birth ssn address
```

Another one is "screening" which keep users' medical test information:

```
id user_id date cholesterol ldl hemoglobin triglycerides mcv glucose 
mchc ha1c plateletcount.
```

One user can only have one record in user table, but could have multiple records in screening table. What I want to do is check the users' multiple screening records that belongs to the same user to see if the combination of those records provide the necessary information I need. If no, the user is selected. For example, the necessary information includes cholesterol, ldl, triglycerides, glucose or . If a user has two screening records, one record provides `cholesterol(NOT NULL)` , another one provides `triglycerides(NOT NULL)`, `glucose(NOT NULL)` and `ha1c(NOT NULL)`. He is selected because ldl is missing.

How do I write the query that is able to do that? I tried inner join, but it seems to not work. There are some requirements here. For cholesterol, ldl and triglycerides, as long as one of them is missing, the user should be selected. But for glucose and ha1c, the user is selected only when both are missing.

One of the query I tried is like this:

```
   SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, clients.name AS client, 
       users.social_security_number AS ssn, users.hiredate, hra.id AS hra_id, hra.date             AS hra_date, hra.maileddate AS hra_maileddate, 
            screening.id AS screening_id, screening.date AS screening_date,         screening.maileddate AS screening_maileddate
        FROM users 
        INNER JOIN clients
        ON(
           users.client_id = clients.id
           )
        INNER JOIN hra
        ON(
           users.id = hra.user_id
           )
        LEFT JOIN screening
        ON(
           users.id = screening.user_id
          )
        WHERE users.client_id = '1879'      
        AND hra.date BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-11-15'
        AND hra.maileddate IS NOT NULL 
        AND screening.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
        AND screening.maileddate IS NULL    
        AND screening.cholesterol IS NOT NULL
        AND screening.ldl IS NOT NULL
        AND screening.triglycerides IS NOT NULL
        AND (screening.glucose IS NOT NULL OR screening.ha1c IS NOT NULL)
        GROUP BY users.id
```

What's the correct query?

Comment: Have a look at the WHERE EXIST clause and (obviously) the WHERE NOT EXIST to check for each client if you can find a record in labs that disqualifies/qualifies the client

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check combination of records from multiple rows(MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335781/how-to-check-combination-of-records-from-multiple-rowsmysql)

Answer (score 0):

Just move conditions that check against labs from `WHERE` to `ON`:

```
    ......
    LEFT JOIN labs
    ON(
       users.id = labs.user_id
       AND labs.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
       AND labs.maileddate IS NULL    
       AND labs.cholesterol IS NOT NULL
       AND labs.ldl IS NOT NULL
       AND labs.triglycerides IS NOT NULL
       AND (labs.glucose IS NOT NULL OR labs.ha1c IS NOT NULL)
      )
    WHERE users.client_id = '1879'      
    AND hra.date BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-11-15'
    AND hra.maileddate IS NOT NULL
```

Do the same for `hra` if you need want your query to return users with no entries in `hra` (don't forget, it should be `LEFT JOIN`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want an OR instead of an AND 
Also, if you want them selected when something is missing, select on "IS NULL", not on "IS NOT NULL"

you start off with finding the user that has an HRA:

```
WHERE users.client_id = '1879'      
    AND hra.date BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-11-15'
```

// Then it seems you want something like this:

```
AND(  labs.cholesterol IS NULL
OR  labs.ldl IS NULL
OR labs.triglycerides IS NULL
OR (labs.glucose IS NULL AND labs.ha1c IS NULL))
```

Comment: I tried, but it still shows users that are not supposed to be selected

Comment: what properties do those users have that makes them qualify as "should not be selected"?

Answer (score 0):

By checking for NOT NULL in the WHERE clause, you defeat the purpose of the LEFT JOIN and in essence, make it into an INNER JOIN...

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, clients.name AS client, 
       users.social_security_number AS ssn, users.hiredate, hra.id AS hra_id, 
       hra.date AS hra_date, hra.maileddate AS hra_maileddate, 
       screening.id AS screening_id, screening.date AS screening_date,                screening.maileddate AS screening_maileddate
FROM users 
INNER JOIN clients  ON(users.client_id = clients.id)
INNER JOIN hra ON(users.id = hra.user_id)
-- This says, find matching records in labs, and if there aren't any, then bring
-- back the fields anyway, filled will NULL's
LEFT JOIN labs ON(users.id = labs.user_id)
WHERE users.client_id = '1879'      
AND hra.date BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-11-15'
AND hra.maileddate IS NOT NULL 
-- These in the WHERE clause defeats the purpose of the LEFT JOIN
-- Move them into the ON condition of the LEFT 
            AND labs.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
            AND labs.maileddate IS NULL    
            AND labs.cholesterol IS NOT NULL
            AND labs.ldl IS NOT NULL
            AND labs.triglycerides IS NOT NULL
            AND (labs.glucose IS NOT NULL OR labs.ha1c IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY users.id
```

When a LEFT JOIN doesn't find matching records, it brings back the fields from a row, but fills their values with NULL's.

Comment: `NOT NULL in the WHERE clause, you defeat the purpose of the LEFT JOIN and in essence, make it into an INNER JOIN...` not necessarily if the field in question is not defined as `not null` then it can contain null even in an inner join. I think that's what the OP meant.